# Error in Chrome only: XMLHttpRequest cannot load URLResponse for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400 NgResource-AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi everyone please would  you like to help me? my app working with NgResource Angular API to make Restfull Calls to Api Server with Java. I am doing a basic  login function.

The function in the controller look like this:

```
    $scope.login = function () {

        AuthService.login($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function (authenticated) {
            $state.go('principal.table', {}, {reload: true});
        }, function (err) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });
        });
    };
```

AuthService has this function of course:

```
  var login = function(name, pw) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        Login.query({user: name+"_"+pw}).$promise.then(function(user) {
      if (usercard[0]  && usercard) {
        resolve('Login success.');
         } else {
        reject('Login Failed.');
      }      
    });
    });
  };
```

The factory Login looks like this:

```
angular.module('login')
.factory('Login', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost:8080/DOGSIAPPREST/resources/Login/:user',  {user:'@user'}, {
     query:{method: "GET", isArray:true}
  });})
```

When I try when the url direct on the browser Chrome I have a response in JSON with the user in a array but using the App I have this: 
[image]

Thanks!! and Best regards!!

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means that you are attempting a malformed request.  It could mean you are trying to POST to a resource mapped to a GET request, or vice versa.  Also, it could mean you are passing data that the resource is not expecting, and thus you are passing a malformed request.

Comment: Ok I will check that but I dont think it could be the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to pass data with the login get request.  You can't pass data with a get request.  The login request is probably a POST, not a GET.  Generally, get can have query string parameters, while post can have a data body, which looks like what you want here.